# why postman is giving 404 error even though the application is running successfully and controller is right? how to resolve this problem?

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, http-status-code-404, spring-restcontroller

I am currently working on a small personal project(springboot + MYSQL), in that while testing in POSTMAN , its showing 404 resource not found .

NOTE: both application and MYSQL is running successfully  without any problem  and POSTMAN is working properly.

controller is fine as of my knowledge.

where is the problem in code? kindly help me out.

**Main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication   

public class CafeManagementSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CafeManagementSystemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**controller**

INTERFACE :

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public interface UserRest {
    
    @PostMapping(path = "/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signup(@RequestBody(required = true) Map<String,String> requestMap);

    
}
```

CLASS:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public class UserRestImpl implements UserRest {
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    
    @PostMapping(path = "/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signup(Map<String, String> requestMap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            return userService.signUp(requestMap);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity(CafeConstants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG,   HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl  implements UserService{

   @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;       // repository
   
   @Override
   public ResponseEntity<String> signUp(Map<String, String> requestMap) {
       
       try {
       
                   log.info("{Inside signUp {}",requestMap);
                   
                   if(validateSignupMap(requestMap)) {    // method present in same class
                        
                       User user=userDao.findByEmailId(requestMap.get("email"));
                       
                       if(Objects.isNull(user)) {
                           userDao.save(getUserFromMap(requestMap));                 
                           return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity("Successfully registered ", HttpStatus.OK);
                       }
                       else {
                           return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity("email already present",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                       }
                       
                   }
                   else {
                       return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity(CafeConstants.INVALID_DATA, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                       
                   }
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       
       return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity(CafeConstants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
       
   }
   
   private Boolean validateSignupMap(Map<String,String> requestMap) {
       
       if(requestMap.containsKey("name") && requestMap.containsKey("contactNumber") && requestMap.containsKey("email") && requestMap.containsKey("password"))
           {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
    }
   
   private User getUserFromMap(Map<String,String> map) {          // MAP to USER object
       
       User u= new User();
       u.setName(map.get("name"));
       u.setContactNumber(map.get("contactNumber"));
       u.setEmail(map.get("email"));
       u.setPassword(map.get("password"));
       u.setStatus("false");
       u.setRole("user");
       
       return u;
       
   }
   
   
   

}
```

**POJO**

```
@NamedQuery(name="User.findByEmailId", query = "select u from User u where u.email=:email")   
                                                                                        

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
public class User  implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "conatactNumber")
    private String contactNumber;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
    
    
    
    

}
```

**REPO **

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    
    User findByEmailId(@Param("email") String email);       
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cafe?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password_root


spring.jpa.show-sql=true       

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

server.port=8081
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.inn.cafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.inn.cafe</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Cafe Management System</name>
    <description>Cafe Management System Project </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
        
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to test in POSTMAN ,but its showing 404 error .

NOTE: postman is working properly ,i have checked by testing another application.

what the problem in the code ? where to look out for in the application

when i hit http://localhost:8081/user/signup , i am getting 404

Comment: The mapping in your controller is a POST mapping, are you sure you're sending a POST request from Postman?

Comment: Did you selected Post method properly and giving correct end point from postman ?

Comment: Please update your question with the postman request that you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you also share your application.properties/yml file. You may have set **server.servlet.context-path=/myApp** something like this and may have forgotten. Or gave a different port number with **server.port=8082**. All and all, sharing your configuration may give more insight about what to look for.

As for the comments about selecting proper Http method; In that case the server would have returned 405: Method Not Allowed. 404 means it couldn't find the requested resource.

**Edit:**

After copy pasting everything, I ran the application and I was definitely able to hit the url.
[PostmanScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joqKv.png).

Something is wrong with your postman maybe? You said postman is working fine but maybe you had a setting(something like a proxy config) there for a specific application.

Can you add these two dependencies and see if you can hit from swagger.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html

I replaced

```java
CafeUtils.getResponseEntity(CafeConstants.INVALID DATA, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

to

```java
new ResponseEntity<>("INVALID DATA", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

everything else is the same as yours.

Comment: i have shared all the files (service, repo , application properties )  just now sir.

Comment: my packages are not auto scanned by springboot.. i used "scanbasePackage " in @springbootApplication in main class to manually scan all the packages.. now its working. i dont know why its not autoscanning. do u have any idea?

Comment: Are all your classes under the same base package ? If it is, normally it should autoscan. Check your project structure and verify that indeed all your classes are under the same base  package. If @SpringBootApplication annotated class' package is com.example.user, your other classes also need to start with that. Your rest controller class' package should be com.example.user.controller per se. Check those, maybe it is com.example.controller.

Answer (score 0):

hey can you provide entity or POJO file and also the UserService file so that we can check the signup fuction under it, i had tried same code and it  worked for me so i guess that there is problem in your signup  method or entity class. So plzz provide that files..!!

Comment: i have shared all the files (service, repo , application properties ) just now sir.

Comment: are u getting response for POST method in postman? usually what would be  the reason for this 404 status though everthing seems alright ?

Answer (score 0):

your endpoint is to get a request , it will only get a response in body x, y ,z.
If you change that endpoint to POST it will not work.
you need the POST endpoint and request to work. Generally, 404 error, when your request is bad. for eg missing something in the request or parameters in headers. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the controller is in the root context path, since it has to be in the same path with the spring boot application main class by default unless modified.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).